# Inverse Mills ratio in system of equations

Tags: endogeneity, heckman

I have been stuck on the following selection/endogeneity problem for a while:

I have a panel dataset with 1.000 products **becoming** fair trade products, all at very different times between 2010 and 2014. For each product, I have weekly sales data for 6 months before they become fair trade up to 1 year after they become fair trade.

In step 1, I estimated the effect of becoming fair trade using a (step) dummy variable that becomes 1 from the week onwards they become fair trade using OLS *for each product individually*. In step 2, I regress the coefficients from the step dummy on about 12 variables (moderaters). I use a 2 step procedure, because 12 interaction effects are not possible to estimate in the same equation due to multicollinearity.

The problem, however, is that brands self-select into joining fair trade or not. I do have data on all products, including those who did not become fair trade.

**In short, my question is:** 
Can I estimate 1 (panel?) selection equation across time across products, and include the same single inverse Mills ratio in each product equation seperately?

Or are there other, better approaches to my problem?

Comment: Edited to Mills ratio (named for John P. Mills).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: No, you cannot use the IMR from a pooled selection equation in the regression in an outcome equation with just a subset of the pooled observations. The outcome equation has to contain all observations, except for those cases that do not fulfill your selection criterion.

However, I think might be a much simpler resolution to your situation:

If the multicollinearity you are concerned about his multicollinearity between the interaction term and its components, you could try standardizing your variables, as suggested [here](http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics/what-are-the-effects-of-multicollinearity-and-when-can-i-ignore-them).

Hope that helps.